# Apache strange behaviour: page loads even when request points to non-existing file

Tags: apache, .htaccess

A client has a website running on a dedicated host (either developed, nor managed by myself) in which Apache is generating a very strange behavior.

When the requested url is of the type:

http://obituarieshelp.org/aboutus.html/whatever_here

it actually loads 'aboutus.html' if it exists, even though 'whatever_here' does not exist, and 'aboutus.html' is not a directory.

I took a look at the htaccess file, and everything seems to be fine. I am sure it is apache misconfigured somehow, but for the love of me, I cannot seem to find anything that could point to the problem in httpd.conf

Has anyone experienced the same, or has any suggestions as to why this would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled by the [`AcceptPathInfo`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#acceptpathinfo) HTTPd directive. The remainder of the path after the file is made available in the `PATH_INFO` environment/server variable, and scripts can use it to discern additional information about the request.